# Force full (100%) CPU utilization on BOINC via boinccmd line utility

Tags: distributed-computing, boinc

I'm running a cloud instance of BOINC and am able to interact with it only via boinccmd over SSH, but I am only seeing CPU utilization remain at 10%.

Resources online for boinccmd don't detail how to set CPU limits. Can anyone assist?

Comment: See https://boinc.berkeley.edu/dev/forum_thread.php?id=3113

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per @tonysdg's comment, the resolution was in setting `<max_ncpus_pct>100.000000</max_ncpus_pct>` in `global_prefs_override.xml` and then forcing the client to re-read preferences with `boinccmd --read_global_prefs_override`.

Comment: You may also need a higher `suspend_cpu_usage` if your project keeps getting suspended https://boinc.berkeley.edu/wiki/Global_prefs_override.xml